# Pandas: take a label from a row of a data frame and convert it to a column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

feature_labels = ["A", "B", "C"]
n_days = 3
n_persons = 2
n_features = len(feature_labels)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "day": np.repeat(list(np.arange(3))*n_persons, n_days),
    "person": np.repeat(np.arange(2), n_days*n_features),
    "feature": feature_labels*(n_days*n_persons),
    "value": np.random.rand(n_features*n_days*n_persons)
})
data
```

It returns:

```
    day feature  person     value
0     0       A       0  0.519279
1     0       B       0  0.243156
2     0       C       0  0.093231
3     1       A       0  0.046888
4     1       B       0  0.775699
5     1       C       0  0.757114
6     2       A       0  0.983894
7     2       B       0  0.709877
8     2       C       0  0.256220
9     0       A       1  0.823253
10    0       B       1  0.014050
11    0       C       1  0.740373
12    1       A       1  0.554485
13    1       B       1  0.828009
14    1       C       1  0.398025
15    2       A       1  0.033659
16    2       B       1  0.904537
17    2       C       1  0.649851
```

I need to get a data table that would have the columns: `day`, `person`, `A`, `B`, and `C`, and contain corresponding values. I would highly appreciate if you could show me how to do that with the APIs of pandas.

Comment: I wish I could give you some sort of bonus points for making your example reproducible! Great job!

Comment: Thank you. To be really reproducible I should be fixing the seed :)

Comment: @desa, not really, we can easily parse the output of your data set, using `pd.read_clipboard()` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [325]: data.set_index(["day", "person", "feature"])['value'] \
              .unstack('feature').reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[325]:
   day  person         A         B         C
0    0       0  0.852395  0.975006  0.884853
1    0       1  0.044862  0.505431  0.376252
2    1       0  0.359508  0.598859  0.354796
3    1       1  0.592805  0.629942  0.142600
4    2       0  0.340190  0.178081  0.237694
5    2       1  0.933841  0.946380  0.602297
```

Explanation:

if we don't specify `['value']` before doing `.unstack()` we will get multi-level columns, because in general we can have multiple non-index columns when "unstacking", so Pandas "stamps" it with the column name:

```
In [328]: data.set_index(["day", "person", "feature"]).unstack('feature')
Out[328]:
               value
feature            A         B         C
day person
0   0       0.852395  0.975006  0.884853
    1       0.044862  0.505431  0.376252
1   0       0.359508  0.598859  0.354796
    1       0.592805  0.629942  0.142600
2   0       0.340190  0.178081  0.237694
    1       0.933841  0.946380  0.602297

In [329]: data.set_index(["day", "person", "feature"])['value'].unstack('feature')
Out[329]:
feature            A         B         C
day person
0   0       0.852395  0.975006  0.884853
    1       0.044862  0.505431  0.376252
1   0       0.359508  0.598859  0.354796
    1       0.592805  0.629942  0.142600
2   0       0.340190  0.178081  0.237694
    1       0.933841  0.946380  0.602297
```

`.rename_axis(None, axis=1)` helps us to get rid of `feature` (name of the 'columns' axis):

```
In [334]: x = data.set_index(["day", "person", "feature"])['value'].unstack('feature').reset_index()

In [335]: x.columns
Out[335]: Index(['day', 'person', 'A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='feature')
# NOTE:                                                                 ^^^^^^^

In [336]: x = x.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

In [337]: x.columns
Out[337]: Index(['day', 'person', 'A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your prompt reply! I just modified the question.. I know `pivot`, however it doesn't work when I call `data.pivot(index=["day", "person"], columns="feature", values="value")`.

Comment: @desa, please post __desired__ (resulting) data set

Comment: The second solution almost works with: `data.set_index(["day", "person", "feature"]).unstack('feature').reset_index()`. However there are stacked column names. First row: `day`, `person`, `values`, second: `feature`, `A`, `B`, `C`. Why it happens and how to make them appear in a single line?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Could you write a more detailed answer explaining how it works? Especially, why you need to call `['value']` before `['value']` and  `.rename_axis(None, 1)` in the end?